# testlink integration with JIRA error

Tags: jira, testlink

I am using testlink 1.9.13 and JIRA 6.2.

I get the following error:

> Source:tlIssueTracker::checkXMLCfg - Failure loading XML STRING StartTag: invalid element name Extra content at the end of the document

Comment: Please elaborate: where does the error show up? what is the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

This particular issue encountered to me as well. 
This error is thrown only when the User Name and Password is incorrect and then the tagging is improper with the proper alignments, the URL which is linked should be properly mentioned.

Comment: Kindly consider this as an example supporting to my answer above and definitely this will be successful as I have solved the same issue :
<issuetracker>
<username>USERNAME</username>
<password>PWD</password>
<uribase>https://URL OF THE WEBSITE /</uribase>
<uriwsdl>https://URL/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl</uriwsdl>
<uriview>https://URL/browse/</uriview>
<uricreate>https://URL/secure
/CreateIssue!default.jspa</uricreate>
<projectkey>TTEST</projectkey>

</issuetracker>